# Is it possible to define a maven goal with a variable?

Tags: maven, javadoc

My question comes from wanting to run javadoc:aggregate for all projects except one, where I want to run javadoc:javadoc (because this one project has a sub-module that needs to use the sourcepath setting in its maven-javadoc-plugin config, as it has generated code as well as source).

And as I understand it there is a bug which means that the sourcepath setting is ignored if you run the aggregate goal. I tried it myself and it did not work and I found: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-311

I have a parent POM which defines the plugin config:

```
<properties>
  <javadoc-goal>aggregate</javadoc-goal>
<properties>
```

i.e.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-javadoc</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>${javadoc-goal}</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
         ...
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I have several projects which inherit from this project. The one where I need to run javadoc instead of aggregate would define:

```
<javadoc-goal>javadoc</javadoc-goal>
```

and its sub-module would define its sourcepath:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java:${basedir}/src/generated/java</sourcepath>
        </configuration>

        ... 
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I am guessing that the answer to my question is no, because when I try and install my parent POM it looks like it is treating the variable as a literal, which I found weird because you can use them in so many other places:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] '${javadoc-goal}' was specified in an execution, but not found in the plugin
```

If I cannot do this, any ideas for working around this problem?

Comment: Ok, so I solved this by defining everything except the plugin goal in the parent POM, then defined the appropriate goal (javadoc or aggregate) in the project POM. Should I delete this question as it no longer requires an answer?

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question; it's [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

Configure the javadoc plugin in the parent POM, but do not provide the goal:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-javadoc</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
         ...
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The in each project POM provide the goal:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-javadoc</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>javadoc</goal> <!-- or aggregate for those projects that require it -->
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```